# Zindex not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a website that I've been Trying to develop, and part of the website is to develop a slideout menu that would slide horizontally out when mouseover. I started with defaulting the menu to be fully extended, such that it would be easier to develop in real time.

For visual reference, I'm attempting to achieve something like this:

```
|--------------|_____________
|Menu 1       >|Menu 1 item 1|
|Menu 2       .|Menu 1 item 2|
|Menu 3       .|Menu 1 item 3|
|______________|_____________|
```

With my code like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #151515;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.5s;

}

#sidebarInfo{
    margin: 0px,5px,10px,5px;
    color: #7E7E7E;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: allerta, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9.5px;
    top: 70%;
    align-content: center;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

.sidebarLi{
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: aliceblue;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: allerta, sans-serif;
}

.slideMenu{
    position:relative;
    transition:0.4s;

}
.menuItem{
    position:relative;
    transition: 0.4s;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    left: 180px;
    z-index: 0;
    color: #000000;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

</style>

<title>Caduceus Technologies</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebarLi">
            &nbsp;•&nbsp;Home
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarLi">
            <div class="slideMenu">
                &nbsp;•&nbsp;Projects
                <div class="menuItem">
                    menuItem1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarLi">
            &nbsp;•&nbsp;Resume
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarLi">
            &nbsp;•&nbsp;Contact
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background:#1D1D1D; position: relative; width:1000px; height: 1000px;">
        Lorem
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, While I cannot upload Images, parsing this document would show you that menuItem one is only partially displayed, even though the Z value dictates that the div with the text "menu Item" would be on top. What exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menuItem1` is partially displayed because your containing `sidebar` div has a fixed width, and has `overflow: hidden`, hiding anything which overflows that container (which `menuItem1` does).

Remove `overflow: hidden` and it's visible (but overflowing your container).

Comment: I override the hidden property with visible in the .menuItem class

Comment: That's not how it works. The parent container has `overflow: hidden`, so anything overflowing that container will be hidden. Setting `overflow: visible` on the child element just means anything that overflows that much smaller container will be visible. The parent container still hides everything.

Comment: making the parent overflow visible simply makes the menu container have a scrollbar, it doesn't extrude the menu from the container.

Comment: I tried it in this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdraXE - is this the behaviour you want?